# .ebextensions with Docker on elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to configure nginx on an elastic beanstalk Docker instance to allow the use of websockets. Using the information found [here](http://dustinbolton.com/websockets-not-working-on-elastic-beanstalk-with-nodejs-when-using-nginx-as-a-proxy/) I added a .ebextensions/01_files.config to the zip I am deploying.

The zip contains .ebextensions/01_files.config, a Dockerfile, and a tgz of my application.

The content of 01_files.config is the following:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websocketupgrade.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection      "upgrade";
```

Elastic beanstalk seemingly ignores my .ebextensions. The file /etc/nginx/conf.d/websocketupgrade.conf is never written.

What is the correct way to use .ebextensions with a Docker container on elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that ElasticBeanstalk overwrites /etc/nginx/conf.d/ as part of the set up an application, so anything you put there with ebextensions will be gone by the time the application has started up.

To get around this, you need to make your changes to the staging area, rather than the final destination. I am not sure what the staging area is for elasticbeanstalk nginx deployments, but if you look in

```
/var/log/eb-activity.log
```

You should be able to figure it out.

You should use the:

```
container_command:
```

directive to make changes to the staging area.

Answer (score -2):

Elastic Beanstalk now supports docker with a lot less hacking, you should be using [Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html).

Just base a new container off the [offical nginx](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) image and add the conf file you have posted above. Then pull in your nginx image using the dockerrun file (See example below).

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "my-bucket",
    "Key": "mydockercfg"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "me/my-nginx-image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear but I am already using the elastic beanstalk Docker container type as you suggest. Nginx is the reverse proxy to the docker container by default in the elastic beanstalk docker container. I need to configure nginx to allow websockets. The issue is that elastic beanstalk seems to ignore my .ebextensions when I deploy.

Comment: Make sure that .ebextensions folder is in the archive that is sent to Elastic Beanstalk. It seems that the easiest solution is to add this folder to your git repo (eb deploy may be doing git --archive under the hood, dunno though).